# Cordova Media Capture - Find duration of audio file

Tags: cordova, audio, telerik

I am writing an app which will take in an audio file and then then upload it to Teleriks everlive service. I want to stop the users from uploading any audio files that are longer than 20 seconds.

But after testing it seems that no matter the duration of the audio file, the "data.duration" always seems to return 0, so no matter what the file is uploaded.

This is the plugin I am using: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

This is my code:

```
    var el = new Everlive('app-id-here'); //Taken away ID for stackoverflow

    var options = {
        fileName: 'testaudio.mp3',
        mimeType: 'audio/mpeg3'
    };

    function formatSuccess(data) {
        if (data.duration > 20) {
            alert("The audio file you have used is longer than 20 seconds.");
        } else {
            alert(data.duration);
            el.files.upload(capturedFiles[0].fullPath, options)
                .then(function () {
                    alert('success');
                }, function (err) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        }

    }

    function formatFail() {
        alert("Error accessing file data");

    }

    capturedFiles[0].getFormatData(formatSuccess, formatFail);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last time I played with this, getDuration only worked when the media file is playing. From my Apache Cordova API Cookbook (www.cordovacookbook.com):

An application can determine the length of a media file using `getDuration` as shown in the following example:

```
console.log('Duration: ' + theMedia.getDuration() + ' seconds');
```

`getDuration` will report a -1 if the audio clip is not currently playing. Unlike `getCurrentPosition`, the `getDuration` method will return the clip length even if playback is paused.

Comment: have you found any solution for this? i am getting -1 for get duration too.